# Javascript relative URLs resolved differently depending on host

Tags: javascript, iis

I'm getting a weird behaviour with javascript which I fail to understand: my application's javascript relative URLs are being resolved differently, depending on where the app is hosted: 
**a)** my computer's IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) or 
**b)** my host provider (which I'm almost sure runs Windows Server 2003).

**Behaviour 1** (the normal one?) - with the app hosted on my computer's IIS

If the browser's current location is http://localhost/appvirtualdir/Newsletter/List
and I run

```
window.location = "../Newsletter/List"
```

inside Firebug's console, the browser is redirected to http://localhost/appvirtualdir/Newsletter/List (remains on the same page).

**Behaviour 2** (the weird one) - with the app hosted on the provider:

If the browser's current location is http://my.domain.com/appvirtualdir/Newsletter/List
and I run *exactly the same script* inside Firebug's console, the browser is redirected to http://my.domain.com/appvdir/Newsletter/Newsletter/List, which obviously doesn't exist.

So, the question is: why, in the second case, is javascript not "moving up the tree"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are on the URL `http://my.domain.com/appvirtualdir/Newsletter/List` and not using `http://my.domain.com/appvirtualdir/Newsletter/List/` (notice the trailing slash)?

The server might think it's a directory (you're redirected to `http://my.domain.com/appvirtualdir/Newsletter/List/`, one way or another, which is possible, as the trailing `/` is simply ignored when file `List` is found in `/appvirtualdir/Newsletter`) and in that case the browser on the client-side thinks you're in directory `List`.

Comment: You're correct, I hadn't noticed that I was being redirected. Let this be a lesson to distracted programmers like myself :-) Since one server puts the trailing slash and the other one doesn't, I am now using a global javascript variable set to app root path. Thank you!